# IDA Change ram and rom without reopen IDA

Tags: ida, static-analysis

when I open binary and write ram and rom , I don't know how to change it (and re parse all the binary) without close and open again the binary.

Is there any smart way ?

Comment: Do you mean changing the loader options? It's not exactly clear (to me) from your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use commands in the Edit-Segments.. menu to create new segments and/or move the existing ones.